# Uninstall program in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

How do I uninstall a program when the Programs and Features tool in the Control Panel says there is not enough memory to uninstall any program every time I try?

Comment: Is your computer really running out of space ?

Comment: Yes. On my C drive where most of my program files are.  I did download Revo Uninstaller and that seems to be working great.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a third party software, like Absolute Uninstaller. I have used it when the control panel said the program is already installed (when it really wasn't), maybe it works for you too.
[Link](http://www.glarysoft.com/absolute-uninstaller/)

You can also try deleting temporary files: Open the Explorer -> Right-click your C-Drive -> There should be a button next to the pie chart that says "clean" or something. Do that. You can get some gigabytes just by that.

> You can delete prefetch data
> C:\Windows\Prefetch
>
> You can delete Windows Update files
> C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
>
> Reduce the size of the system swap.
> Right click on Computer -> Select Properties -> Click "Advanced System Settings" in the left pane -> In the Advanced tab, under Performance, click Settings -> Click on the Advanced tab -> Click Change -> resize it to something smaller. I wouldn't go under 768 MB
>
> You can remove non-essential windows components in control panel -> programs & > features -> Turn windows components on or off
>
> *Source: [tomshardware.co.uk](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/289293-32-storage-space-drive)*

And you can delete files that are not needed anymore (if you have them). If you want that, open the Explorer, open the drive you want to clean. Type "size:gigantic." in the search field. Right-click the results pane, sort by -> size.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Answer (score 0):

Use a third-party uninstaller software, like IObit uninstaller, etc.

And most importantly clean up some space, or you are going to get some trouble with your PC. ;)

Comment: I thought that by uninstalling unused programs I would clean up some space but it didn't change anything.  I did download Revo Uninstaller and that seems to be working great to uninstall the programs, but it still looks like it is not freeing up any space on my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a lot of space by removing extra files from Winsxs folder [Disk cleanup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update.aspx)

Before that, you need to remove some file. As said in the first answer, you can delete the content of Softwaredistribution folder, but stopping the Windows Update service before.